# Mixed model idea and Bayesian method

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model

In mixed model, we assume the random effects (parameters) are random variables that follow normal distributions. It looks very similar to the Bayesian method, in which all the parameters are assumed to be random.

So is the random effect model kind of special case of Bayesian method?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a good question. Strictly speaking, using a mixed model does not make you Bayesian. Imagine estimating each random effect separately (treating it as a fixed effect) and then looking at the resulting distribution. This is "dirty," but conceptually you have a probability distribution over the random effects based on a *relative frequency* concept.

But if, as a frequentist, you fit you model using full maximum likelihood and then wish to "estimate" the random effects, you've got a little complication. These quantities aren't fixed like your typical regression parameters, so a better word than "estimation" would probably be "prediction." If you want to predict a random effect for a given subject, you're going to want to use that subject's data. You'll need to resort to Bayes' rule, or at least the notion that $$f(\beta_i | \mathbf{y}_i) \propto f(\mathbf{y}_i | \beta_i) g(\beta_i).$$ Here the random effects distribution $g()$ works essentially like a prior. And I think by this point, many people would call this "empirical Bayes."

To be a true Bayesian, you would not only need to specify a distribution for your random effects, but distributions (priors) for each parameter that defines that distribution, as well distributions for all fixed effects parameters and the model epsilon. It's pretty intense!

Comment: Really clear, straightforward answer.

Comment: @baogorek - a fairly robust default is Cauchy priors for fixed effects and half cauchy for variance parameters - not that "intense" - it just looks like penalised likelihood

Comment: I realise this was answered almost 10 years ago, I was just a bit unsure about something from this answer. I think I'm misunderstanding something, but why, in a frequentist setting, aren't you able to estimate the random effects by estimating the parameters of the assumed distribution of the effect with ML?

Comment: @Geoff Time flies! By parameters, I assume you mean the beta_i's and not a fixed effect parameter like beta_bar (the average) and ML is maximum likelihood. If you treat the beta_i's like parameters and estimate them, then you're out of a random effects framework and back into fixed effects, aka, just a bunch of regressions. You get more flexibility by doing that but for i's with small sample sizes the beta_i estimates will be all over the place. You could add a penalty term to the likelihood to stabilize. Actually I think lme4 "estimates" the random effects in this way & backs into the rest.

Comment: @BenOgorek Had to do a bit of reading around, hence the delay. I thought an RE is defined by assigning a distribution to a parameter, then including that distribution into the LL and carrying out MLE with inference following as normal. With the point about going from random to fixed once estimated, is this because in a Bayesian setting, direct inference are made on a random variables, which is the parameter itself in this case, as it is sampled from the posterior; and, if so, in the case of large enough clusters, and in terms of inference, are they operationally distinct?

Comment: @Geoff In the parameter estimation of the fixed effects parameters, you're right that the RE distributions go in the LL but then REs themselves are integrated out to get a marginal distribution (likelihood) w/o them. The "prediction" of the REs is a second step because in the LL, they weren't parameters that had to be estimated (only their mean and variance). Their predictions are interesting secondary quantities. I'm not fully following the second part of your question, but I think my throwing in the alternate estimation methods was a bit of a red herring.

Answer (score 4):

Random effects are a way to specify a distributionial assumption by using conditional distributions. For example, the random one-way ANOVA model is:
$$(y_{ij} \mid \mu_i) \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu_i, \sigma^2_w), \quad j=1,\ldots,J, 
\qquad 
\mu_i \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}(\mu, \sigma^2_b), \quad i=1,\ldots,I.$$ 
And this distributional assumption is equivalent to 
$$\begin{pmatrix} y_{i1} \\ \vdots \\ y_{iJ} \end{pmatrix} \sim_{\text{iid}} {\cal N}\left(\begin{pmatrix} \mu \\ \vdots \\ \mu \end{pmatrix}, \Sigma\right), \quad i=1,\ldots,I$$
where $\Sigma$ has an exchangeable structure (with diagonal entry $\sigma^2_b+\sigma^2_w$ and covariance $\sigma^2_b$).
To Bayesianify the model, you need to assign prior distributions on $\mu$ and $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking in terms of reproducing the same answers, then the answer is yes.  The INLA (google "inla bayesian") computational method for bayesian GLMMs combined with a uniform prior for the fixed effects and variance parameters, basically reproduces the EBLUP/EBLUE outputs under the "simple plug in" gaussian approximation, where the variance parameters are estimated via REML.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so,  I consider it part of the likelihood function.  It's similar to specifying the error term follows a Normal distribution in a regression model, or a certain binary process can be modeled using a logistic relationship in a GLM.

Since no prior information, or distributions, are used I do not consider it Bayesian.

Comment: No prior information used hey?  How did you specify the functional form for the likelihood function then? :-D

Comment: Some people argue that the distinction between likelihood and prior is somewhat artificial.